# Public key authentication plus challenge authentication

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, google-authenticator

I am trying to setup 2-phase authentication based on [this guide](http://www.debiantutorials.com/secure-ssh-with-two-factor-authentication-using-google-authenticator-on-squeeze/), but instead of entering the password I would like public key to be involved.

If `PubkeyAuthentication yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_conf` then 2 factor authentication phase is not executed (I get the shell) but I want the challenge to be asked. If I set `PubkeyAuthentication no`, then the whole authentication cycle is executed (I am asked a password and then the challenge), but I want pubkey to be used instead of password.

How to achieve it?

Similar topic is [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/353743/openssh-how-to-require-publickeyauthentication-and-login-password-authentica).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/629883

Comment: I agree with you.